# Fake parallelization in script over loop (foreach line) without substantial changes in code

Tags: loops, parallel-processing, csh, gnu-parallel

I am new to GNU Parallel and I will be glad if you point out some errors and misunderstandings. I read the manual but it says basically about one-stage operation in which it is necessary to specify the definition of "action" in the syntax GNU Parallel (unpacking, moving and etc) and nothing is specified about the multi-stage steps when you need to perform a few actions without changing (significantly) the code (if the course is at all possible)

Is it possible to "fake" parallel processing in the code that does not support it? 
The code has a loop (there are included list of files in any format, and at some point it comes to loop) and all you need that code to perform certain actions (no matter what kind of actions) on all files simultaneously rather than sequentially (without changing the code substantially or only around 138 line - *see below*). It's that kind of parallel processing is not required to split files or something like that, but just to processing all files at once.

As example: here is a part of code that interests, full code here - 138 line [GMT](http://gmt.soest.hawaii.edu/projects/gmt5sar/repository/entry/branches/5.2_KF/gmtsar/csh/intf_tops.csh)

```
# <code> actions (see full code - link below) and check input file availability
#loop
#
  foreach line (`awk '{print $0}' $1`)
# <code> actions (see full code - link below)
end if
```

Source, full code: [GMT](http://gmt.soest.hawaii.edu/projects/gmt5sar/repository/entry/branches/5.2_KF/gmtsar/csh/intf_tops.csh)

Maybe it can be implemented using other tools besides the GNU Parallel? Any help is useful. It is desirable for example if any. And if you make all of the code parallel, it probably will cause problems. It's necessary at the moment of the loop.

Thanks

Comment: Is there any reason to use `csh` rather than `bash`? You seem to spend your whole script running many invocations of `awk` which would be entirely unnecessary in `bash`. You can also put all your code in a `function` if you use `bash`, then `export` the function to **GNU Parallel** and run the function in parallel with `parallel someFunc`.

Comment: Also, try to avoid things like `grep XYZ someFile | awk 'print $3'` and instead let `awk` do the searching too like this `awk '/XYZ/{print $3}' someFile`

Comment: It will be very difficult to rewrite everything in `bash`. And the code is not mine. Especially since I'm still just learning. Many pitfalls and so on. But I ask the developers (ie can i rewrite to bash). Thank you for idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

csh has many limitations; lack of functions is one of them, and any script that's longer than a few lines will quickly turn into a spaghetti mess. This is an important reason why scripting in csh is typically discouraged.

That being said, the easiest way to modify this is to extract the loop body out to a separate script and call that with `&` appended. For example:

`main.csh`:

```
#!/bin/csh

foreach line (`awk '{print $0}' $1`)
    ./loop.csh "$line" &
end
```

`loop.csh`:

```
#!/bin/csh

set line = "$1"
echo "=> $line"
sleep 5
```

You may need to add more parameters than just `$line`; I didn't check the entire script.

The `&` will make the shell continue without waiting for the command to finish. So if there are 5,000 lines you will be running 5,000 processes at the same time. To exercise some control over the number of simultaneous processes you could use the parallel tool instead of a loop:

```
#!/bin/csh

awk '{print $0}' $1 | parallel ./loop.csh`
```

Or if you want to stick with loops you can use `pgrep` to limit the maximum number of simultaneous processes:

```
foreach line (a b c d e f g h i)
    set numprocs = `pgrep -c loop.csh`
    if ( $numprocs > 2 ) then
        sleep 2
        continue
    endif

    ./loop.csh "$line" &
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try.

Answer (score 1):

If it is acceptable to move the inner part of the loop into a script:

```
parallel inner.csh ::: a b c d e f g h i
```

If `inner.csh` uses variables, then `setenv` them before running `parallel`:

```
setenv myvar myval
parallel inner.csh ::: a b c
```

`a, b, and c` will be passed as the first arg to `inner.csh`. To read the arguments from a file use:

```
cat file | parallel inner.csh
```

This also works for reading output from `awk`:

```
awk ... | parallel ...
```

Consider walking through the tutorial. Your commandline will love your for it: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Comment: Could you tell me what to do with the variables? I understand if they are set before the loop and then used in loop,  GNU Parallel will launch new processes which are not related to them. And the code will not work. Any tips is useful. Thank you for help. Instead of `a b c f e f `, I should to use file names?